# Appstore submission Error - No Suitable application records where found.Verify your bundle identifier 'org.webrtc.WebRtc'

Tags: ios, objective-c, jitsi

Appstore submission Error - No Suitable application records where found.Verify your bundle identifier 'org.webrtc.WebRtc', i have checked provisioning profile bundle id and it is not and issue ,Actually this issue occurs due to add thirdparty  SDK in my project as pod file

Answer (score 0):

Just check that app you configured on iTuneconnect is having same bundle identifier that you are using to upload app.

Comment: i have checked out the bundle identifier that is also not an issue